# Default application in URL

Tags: python, web2py

If I create an application and some controller, by default I will access it using:

http:// 127.0.0.1/application/controller/function

I want to change the behaviour of the URLs that I can access any controller by not asking for the application part. Using my example, I want to be able to access all the controllers of my app like this:

```
http:// 127.0.0.1 /application/controller/function1  
http:// 127.0.0.1 /application/controller2/function2
http:// 127.0.0.1 /application/controller2/function3  (and etc.)
```

What I want to do is remove the need to indicate the application to be able to access all my controllers like this:

```
http:// 127.0.0.1/controller/function1
http:// 127.0.0.1/controller2/function2
http:// 127.0.0.1/controller2/function3  (and etc.)
```

---

Modifying my routes.py:

```
# routes.py
default_application = 'application'
default_controller = 'controller'
default_function = 'index'
```

I can access http://127.0.0.1/ and I am redirected to http://127.0.0.1/controller/index
  But If I try to access other function I need to indicate the application.

I didn't find a good reference about how routes.py can be configured, and I think that I have to change this file to get what I want.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The web2py URL rewrite functionality is explained in [the book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#URL-Rewrite). Note, you have a choice between the newer (and simpler) [parameter-based system](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Parameter-Based-System) and an alternative [pattern-based system](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Pattern-Based-System) (which provides some additional flexibility for more complex cases). In your case, the parameter-based system would be easiest -- just include the following in your `routes.py` file:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = 'application',
        default_controller = 'controller',
    ),
)
```

If you need additional help, I would recommend asking on the [web2py mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).